# Are you allowed to use your app's flat iOS 7 icon on iOS 6, or does it have to have the gloss effect?

Tags: ios, xcode

iOS 6 icons had the semi circle gloss effect, for consistency are you allowed to remove the gloss effect for iOS 6 devices so the iOS 6 and 7 icons are identical? I know you can do it in Xcode, but is this against the rules? The option in Xcode is assuming you've already applied the gloss effects.

Answer (score 0):

Apple doesn't have any restrictions concerning gloss/non-gloss effects on app icons. [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/MobileHIG/AppIcons.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH19-SW1) doesn't mention anything about it either so you don't have to worry, go for it.